Oauth failure with PHPMailer and Gmail
I've been through many of the questions/responses relating to this and none of the suggestions have solved the problem.
A bit of back story:
I run a club website and used the inbuilt PHP mail() functionality to be sent emails when a member updated their details. With providers and email relays tightening their security this has become increasingly less reliable. Thus I decided to use PHPMailer to send the emails via GMail. So...

Created a user app in Google Cloud.

Created an OAuth 2.0 client ID for the app.

Used PHPMailer/get_oauth_token.php along with the client ID and
client secret to create a refresh token.

Added gmail access scopes to the app.


I'm using the example PHPMailer script - https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail_xoauth.phps with my values substituted.
Unfortunately I get the following:
2024-12-15 15:48:46 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: EHLO myclub.org.uk<br>
2024-12-15 15:48:46 SERVER -&gt; CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [79.170.40.34]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8<br>
2024-12-15 15:48:47 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: AUTH XOAUTH2 dXNlcj1ib2JncmFoYW1jbHViQGdtYWlsLmNvbQFhdXRoPUJlYXJlciB5YTI5LmEwQVJXNW03NzZyNjA3UHNOTjNPWjdjamZTMTJESlZwb09fXzBKdzg1VnBuR05nMWFrcS1JTVBIZENKcjlKZW01dmxBN0tRS05RNF9XUVN0Tks5cVM3eG5HUHhLV1pOMm9OaGVXTnVoYjgyYll6bGFGT2pBX1hheFh3c0J5S1hHRXZTRWx6dUVZZUlldUdLeXpXRlN1VFk1YjhrNi12TWhtTzJOU2NDQ1pOSklEa3hxRE1hQ2dZS0Fha1NBUklTRlFIR1gyTWlBbm9GUk5Cd2V6RlgteGFqeHdDdWdRMDE4MwEB<br>
2024-12-15 15:48:47 SERVER -&gt; CLIENT: 334 eyJzdGF0dXMiOiI0MDAiLCJzY2hlbWVzIjoiQmVhcmVyIiwic2NvcGUiOiJodHRwczovL21haWwuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS8ifQ==<br>
2024-12-15 15:48:47 SMTP ERROR: AUTH command failed: 334 eyJzdGF0dXMiOiI0MDAiLCJzY2hlbWVzIjoiQmVhcmVyIiwic2NvcGUiOiJodHRwczovL21haWwuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS8ifQ==<br>
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.<br>
2024-12-15 15:48:47 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: QUIT<br>
2024-12-15 15:48:47 SERVER -&gt; CLIENT: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. For more information, go to535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials 5b1f17b1804b1-4363606ece8sm57588185e9.25 - gsmtp<br>
2024-12-15 15:48:47 SMTP ERROR: QUIT command failed: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. For more information, go to535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials 5b1f17b1804b1-4363606ece8sm57588185e9.25 - gsmtp<br>
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.<br>

Not sure why I get the "Username & Password not accepted" since I'm using OAuth.
Now I've missed something (I might also have missed steps I've done from the above) or I've done something wrong but I'm at a loss to what it is.
Edit: The suggested answer relates to the Zend stack and doesn't mention anything about an apps password.
Regarding the use of an apps password - this How to use PHPMailer, after 30 May 2022 when "Less secure app" is no longer an option? suggests that it's no longer an option. Also this suggestion:

First go to your google account management and go to security.
Make sure your 2-step verification are enabled.
Then go to app password.
Select other in the select app dropdown menu, and named whatever you like.
And click generate, google will give you a password. make sure you copy it and save it somewhere else.
instead using your real google account password in PHPMailer setting, use the password you just generate.

No longer seems to be an option, it's not something that's apparent in Account->security

You need to use an apps password

This question is similar to: How to implement Gmail OAuth API to send email (especially via SMTP)?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
